# Publish Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-sdk

I have created an app using Xamarin, and it works great on Testflight and Google Play beta-testing (I am not ready to launch completely yet, but nearly).

I need to know, how am I going to create the package for Windows Store (or what it is called?).

Comment: You mean this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975357.aspx

Comment: I only have Launch Windows App Certification Kit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing a windows phone app, you should have a developer account.
Now if you are ready to publish (or even before) go to the **Windows Dev Center** and create a new app in there. There you can see the following steps to publish your app in the windows app store. 
If you don´t know what your developer account is or you don´t have one, start here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows

Comment: I have a developer account. I only needs to know, how I can create the package for the app in Visual Studio.

Comment: Sorry for answering that late, I´m not in the office. After running the certification kit you have got an item like "create app package" or something like that within the build tap. Push that and you´ll find an apk file in your /bin/release folder --> you need release configuration, pointing to arm platform